# How can I open an pskx file in blender?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, import

So i need to import an PSKX file into blender but i have tried almost everything getting rid of the x from .PSKX and also this add-on script([Link](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?337493-Importing-Static-Mesh-From-Unreal-Engine-(*-pskx))) i have even tried opening it in unreal engine 3 and 4 the UPK file at lest i also tried umodel maya and nothing works but i have heard of a remodify file of the link i put in but can't find it anyway i just want to export it to any file that blender can read.

Answer (score 2):

I use the exact same script you linked to and I works fine.
You don't have to get rid of the 'x" in the end as this is only a suffix Gildor, the creator of umodel, introduced because his tool adds some additional values useful to modders. The downside is that a PSKX file cannot be opened inside the UDK. The 'x' simply tells the user that this is psk has been modified.